# How to use Iterator/Enumeration Interface in Java

Tags: java, iterator, enumeration

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Difference between Java Enumeration and Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948194/difference-between-java-enumeration-and-iterator)

I was reading this post "[Difference between Iterator & Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/948194/difference-between-java-enumeration-and-iterator)"

If can use either iterator methods or enumeration methods to perform the same action then what is the difference?

Where am I expected to use either of these interfaces?

Comment: I don't get what you need that wasn't in the duplicate. The accepted answer seems clear and complete. Can you explain your problem ?

Comment: Does hasMoreElement() and hasNext() mean the same?

Comment: Yes. They're the same. One will save some precious octets on your hard disk.

Comment: Enumerators are a legacy Java 1.0 interface. Except for some APIs that still survive from then, you can pretend they don't exist. (Same goes for the old collection classes like `Vector` and `Hashtable`.) Use iterators or the enhanced for loop.

Comment: Ok, It's preferred to use Iterators/Enhanced for-loops instead of Enumerations right?

Comment: @Appsheriff: Yes, they mean the same thing...but you can't use them interchangeably since one requires you to have an `Iterator` and the other requires you to have an `Enumeration`.  Anyway, `Enumeration` has fallen out of use (it doesn't have language-level support like `Iterator` does).

Comment: Thanks Guys, I got the answers I was looking for...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enumerators are part of legacy Java 1.0.  Iterators only appeared in Java 1.2.  To my knowledge, Enumerators are only kept for backward compatibility.  As per the [java docs for Enumerator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Enumeration.html), all new code should user the Iterator interface.

> NOTE: The functionality of this interface is duplicated by the
>   Iterator interface. In addition, Iterator adds an optional remove
>   operation, and has shorter method names. New implementations should
>   consider using Iterator in preference to Enumeration.

You should use Iterators when looping through a collection, list, set, etc or something that implements that Iterator interface.  You can also use the "new" (Java 5) for loop construct to iterate over such a collection.  Keep in mind, however, that the only safe way to remove an item from a collection when looping is to use the Iterator.remove() method.

Answer (score 3):

Iterator is the newer, preferred method. It adds a remove function.

Answer (score 1):

Enumeration is used to get successive elements in lists, and cannot be used to alter the list in any way, such as through insertion or deletion.  However, an iterator is an instantiated object that maintains a reference in the list, and can insert and delete elements at that reference, along with getting the elements in the list.

If you simply want to get the elements in a list, both enumeration and the use of an iterator will work fine.  However, if you need the added function of insertion and deletion, I recommend using an iterator.

Comment: I dont'see any method to insert using Iterator.

Comment: Yes you are correct in terms of the Java API, my mistake.  However, in terms of implementing iterators, insertion methods are often created.

Comment: Yes, I agree with that. Thank You.